# How to get the highest index value of a duplicate element in a list in Python

Tags: python

I want to sort an array and find the change in the number of indices after sorting
Here is the code that I have written

```py
dummy = list(map(int, input().split()))

i = 1
counts = 0
while True:
    print("\n")
    print("Iteration", i)
    emp = []
    if i + 1 > len(dummy):
        break

    if i == 1:
        uns = dummy[:i + 1]
    else:
        uns = whole[:i + 1]
    print("Unsorted Array is: ", uns)
    new = sorted(dummy[:i + 1])
    print("Now Considering: ", new)
    whole = new + dummy[i + 1:]
    print("The Whole Array is: ", whole)
    if whole != dummy:
        # print("Not Same!")
        for i in range(len(new)):
            old = uns.index(uns[i])
            print("Old value of", uns[i], "is: ", old)
            new_in = new.index(uns[i])
            print("New value of", uns[i], "is: ", new_in)
            diff = abs(old - new_in)
            print("Difference in the index value of ", uns[i], "is: ", diff)
            emp.append(diff)
        counts += max(emp)
        print("Max difference is: ", max(emp), "The count now is: ", counts)
    i += 1

print(counts)
```

The input to the code is `2 1 3 1 2`
it sorts i+1 elements in every iteration

but in iteration 3 when the elements taken into consideration are `1 2 3 1` (This is after 2 iterations of sorting) it returns the previous value(index) of `1` as 0 instead of 3, how do I get 3 (i.e the highest index value of a duplicate element) instead of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `start` parameter of the `list.index()` method to start your search only after the previous occurence:

```py
    dummy_list = [1, 2, 3, 1]

    first_idx = dummy_list.index(1)
    print(first_idx)  # prints 0

    print(dummy_list.index(1, first_idx + 1))  # prints 3
```

See the [Python documentation on data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more information.

Comment: If you want to change as little as possible, you could reversed(range()). But the other answer is more pythonic.